# Android shared title bar with functionality

Tags: android, titlebar

I have a custom title bar cross all of activities.
The problem is that I need to write this code

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.vitamin_chart);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
```

on all of activities.

Is there a way to write the setting of title bar and functionality in one place?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make an abstract class `TitleBarActivity` with this code and then `extend TitleBarActivity` from all of your other activities. (Be sure that `TitleBarActivity extends Activity`.)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, This works very well. Thanks.

Comment: I got null pointer exception on (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vitaminEditButton), which it couldn't find any resource when I move to next activity startActivity(intent);

Comment: Just figure out, need to add setContentView(R.layout.summary);

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ActionBarActivity the use this `getActionBar().setTitle("your_custom_title_here")`